# DBeaver launch script from file

Tags: oracle, dbeaver

I'm trying to find a good alternative to SQL Developer for performing queries and scripts on Oracle instances.

I find ***DBeaver*** to be an interesting tool, it has a lot of great features, ***BUT*** it seems to lack an essential element: The possibility to launch scripts from the filesystem of the client machine in a batch-like way.

For example, in SQL Developer I simply put a file called *delta_script.sql* that contains:

```
@script1.sql
@script2.sql
@script3.sql
```

I execute it as a script and the software executes all of the files in the correct order (provided that they are in the same directory as the delta_script.sql file).

On DBeaver, this does not happen, instead I get a *[900] **ORA-00900**: invalid SQL statement.*.

How can I manage this to work as expected?

I have tried the following in the delta_script.sql file with no luck:

- @@ scriptN.sql
- @/tmp/folder/scriptN.sql
- @"/tmp/folder/scriptN.sql"
- @"scriptN.sql"

They're all giving the same error, so I think there's a problem with the "@".
I have tried from SQLPlus with the synthax I use on SQL Developer without errors.

Comment: this would help. http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=744

Comment: I was aware of this feature. Like this I'm not able to launch all the script in a folder sequentially.

Comment: why are you looking for an alternative to SQLDev?

Comment: The "@" syntax is a sqlplus directive, also supported by SQL Dev.  It is NOT a sql syntax, so there should be no expectation that it would be supported by other client programs.  I agree with Jeff, why not just use SQL Dev?

Comment: That is not true because with Toad for Oracle you can use the @ as in SQLDev for launching scripts. The reason why I'm looking for a SQL Dev alternative is because I don't find it very stable, it's limited to Oracle and since I have to manage also MySQL and Postgres database, I'm looking for an unified solution.

Answer (score 0):

Arobase `@` is an SQLPlus alias.

https://datacadamia.com/lang/sqlplus/arobase

> Alias
> The character specials @ can also be used to start a script.
> The character special @@ permits to start it from a relative path.
> ? means the ORACLE Home directory

It is an equivalent for `START`

https://datacadamia.com/lang/sqlplus/start_command

> Syntax 
> STA[RT] {url|file_name} [arg ...]

Make sure you use the "Execute in SQL Plus" (when connected, right click on connection > Tools > "Execute in SQL Plus") option.